# Possible to return capture using Perl's grep and regex

Tags: regex, perl, grep

Is it possible to return just the captured portion of a regex using Perl's grep function?  I have code such as the following:

```
use LWP::Simple;
my $examples_content = get('http://example.com/javascript/reports/examples/');
my @hrefs = grep(/href="(.*)"/, split("\n", $examples_content));
print $hrefs[0];
```

What gets printed though is:

Stand-alone single-question charts

When I'd like just: simple_chart.html

Comment: To solve your original problem however you might want to have a look at: http://search.cpan.org/~bdfoy/HTML-SimpleLinkExtor-1.25/lib/HTML/SimpleLinkExtor.pm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you using `grep`? This might do what you want:

```
my @hrefs = $examples_content =~ /href="(.*?)"/g
```

Answer (score 4):

Someone already mentioned this in a comment, but if you are dealing with HTML, I have a module that extract links. If you don't mind depending on HTML::Parser, it's not a bad little tool:

```
    use HTML::SimpleLinkExtor;

    my $extor = HTML::SimpleLinkExtor->new;
    $extor->parse($html);

    @a_hrefs     = $extor->a;    # by tag
    @hrefs       = $extor->href; # by attribute
```

I mostly use this module for quick and dirty jobs. Since it uses a real HTML parser, it won't extract the false positives, such as similar things in the text (inside of tags).

Most other people already addressed the issues with `map` and `split`, but you need to be careful with the regexes too:

```
 my @hrefs = map {
      / \s href \s* = \s* (['"]) (.*?) \1 /ix ? $2 : ()
     } @lines;
```

You can see different quoting characters (or none at all), and case insensitive tags and attributes. No matter what any spec or standard says, lots of things generate messed up HTML and many browsers support it. I'm probably still missing things in that pattern. That's why I wrote the module.

Answer (score 3):

`grep` might be the wrong tool for the job. Try just `$examples_content =~ /href="(.*?)"/g` … no need to `split` first, and the `?` modifier will keep the `href=".*"` pattern from matching too much.

Answer (score 3):

`map` can emulate `grep` easily by either returning or not returning a value:

```
my @hrefs = map(/href="(.*?)"/g, split("\n", $examples_content));
```

but I agree with *Amadan* and *BRPocock* that removing the split and just matching against the source in this case will work better, but I added this as an answer to show you how `map` can be used for other cases.

in the spirit of more than one way to do it, the line:

```
my @hrefs = $examples_content =~ /href="(.*?)"/g;
```

could also be written:

```
my @hrefs = map /href="(.*?)"/g, $examples_content;
```

if you prefer the order *[output transform input]* rather than *[output input transform]*

Comment: Haven't tried it (have gotten the other answers to work), but I was thinking about running my original output through map, though of course your one-step suggestion is much better.  As always TMTOWTDI